# Get HDR image from images with different exposure times

Tags: c++, image, camera, hdr

I'm working on a project where we use an HDR sensor.

We are reading 4 'images' per image -> 4 different exposure times.

What's the best way to 'mix' these 4 images in order to get an output image with the highest posible dynamic range?

Has someone a good example without extern libraries as OpenCV?

This should work in real time in a C++ application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many open-source projects doing this, but one that I like in particular is [HDRview](https://bitbucket.org/wkjarosz/hdrview) which does not use any external libraries for implementing the tone-mapping.